# count of last continuous inserted records based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I want to get the count of last continuous inserted records.

I have the table as

```
user_id | point |   DateTime
1       |   10  |   18-08-2018 17:15
2       |   10  |   01-08-2018 17:15
1       |   10  |   21-08-2018 17:15
1       |   10  |   22-08-2018 17:15
2       |   10  |   26-08-2018 17:15
1       |   10  |   25-08-2018 17:15
2       |   10  |   27-08-2018 17:15
1       |   10  |   26-08-2018 17:15
1       |   10  |   27-08-2018 17:15
```

Now there are 6 records for user_id  = 1

But I want to count for last continuous records of the previous date

So the expected output should be count

> 3

because

```
27-08-2018
26-08-2018
25-08-2018
```

above dates are consecutive and then there is a gap between `25-08-2018` to `22-08-2018`

If another record is present for `24-08-2018` then output should be

> 4

Here my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e5a27/2)

Comment: Short answer: impossible by pure SQL. If you can add a column to store the "continuous days", it can be easier, you just need to calculate that value on every insertion.

Comment: What's your mysql version Did it support window function?

Comment: @D-Shih I don't know about window function and mysql version is 5.6.

Comment: you need procedure... just one sql query can not solve this problem

Comment: @shawn No I cant add any extra column.

Comment: Store dates as dates. Then get back to us.

Comment: Then you are on the wrong way. See you.

Comment: What if today is the 29th, and there's no record for the 28th?

Comment: @Strawberry I want to add points based on count of previous visit. If today is 29th and there's no record for the 28th then new entry inserted with points defined for 1st entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to let `DateTime` column be `datetime` type

It is a *Gaps and Islands* question, you can try to make row number by `user_id` and difference days number from each `min(datetime)` from each `user_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`user_id` varchar(12), `point` varchar(9), `DateTime` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`user_id`, `point`, `DateTime`)
VALUES
    ('1', '10', '2018-08-18 17:15'),
    ('2', '10', '2018-08-01 17:15'),
    ('1', '10', '2018-08-21 17:15'),
    ('1', '10', '2018-08-22 17:15'),
    ('2', '10', '2018-08-26 17:15'),
    ('1', '10', '2018-08-25 17:15'),
    ('2', '10', '2018-08-27 17:15'),
    ('1', '10', '2018-08-26 17:15'),
    ('1', '10', '2018-08-27 17:15')

;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT cnt
FROM (
  SELECT rn,MAX(DateTime) mxDt,COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM (
      SELECT DateTime,datediff(DateTime,mDt) -(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM Table1 tt 
                WHERE t2.DateTime >= tt.DateTime 
                and t2.user_id = tt.user_id
               ) rn
      FROM (
        SELECT user_id,MIN(DateTime) mDt
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY user_id
      ) t1 INNER JOIN Table1 t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
      Where t1.user_id = 1 ##set your expect select user_id
    ) t1
  GROUP BY rn
)t1 
ORDER BY mxDt desc
LIMIT 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2412a7/36/0)**:

```
| cnt |
|-----|
|   3 |
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to re-read op. He is looking for the latest consecutive date amount

Comment: Now we just have to decide whether or not '1' constitutes a 'streak', but the OP hasn't said.

Comment: Thanks you for your help, this query works for me. But as Strawberry raised a point if there is not yesterdays record. Then count would be 0. For that I need to add 1 where condition, so I sorted that out. Here is [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4181b/1)

Comment: So,Do you need to count be 0 if there isn't any count of last continuous ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,dt DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (dt) VALUES
('2018-08-18'),
('2018-08-01'),
('2018-08-21'),
('2018-08-22'),
('2018-08-26'),
('2018-08-25'),
('2018-08-27'),
('2018-08-26'),
('2018-08-27');

SELECT i 
  FROM
     (
       SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = dt 
                   THEN @i:=@i 
                   WHEN @prev = dt-INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                   THEN @i:=@i+1 
                   ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev := dt prev
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars
        ORDER 
           BY dt 
            , id
     ) a
 ORDER 
    BY dt DESC
     , id DESC
 LIMIT 1;

+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    3 |
+------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your precious time. I appreciate your help.